# Adding observations and variables to a dataset with .csv files in Stata

Tags: database, merge, dataset, append, stata

I am using Stata 17. I want to add observations and variables in a dataset, I'll name it dataset1.

Dataset1 has the following structure

```
Date    Year   urbanname  urbancode etc..

2010m1  2010    Beijing   1029 ...
2010m2  2010    Beijing   1029 ...
2010m3  2010    Beijing   1029 ...
...
2015m1  2015     Paris    1030 etc
```

For different cities and different time periods.

I would like to add observations of other cities (that are not in the rows of dataset1), that I have in different .csv files (dataset2.csv, dataset3.csv, and so on..). Each city has its own dataset.
In each .csv dataset I want to add I have the following variables

1. the dates
2. the urbanname
3. the urbancode
4. other variables which I do not yet have in dataset1 but that I want to add

What would be your advice on how to proceed ? I thought of doing it with R but dataset1 does not open well in RStudio and the variable Date is not well imported.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1672201-adding-observations-to-a-dataset-with-csv-files-and-a-loop It is polite to tell people about cross-posting.

Comment: I did not know this implicit rule. I beg your pardon.

Answer (score 1):

You do not describe what you have tried so far and what issues you are encountering but you can do something like this:

```
use dataset1, clear

* Store in the data in a temporary file
tempfile appendfile
save `appendfile`

foreach dataset in dataset2.csv dataset3.csv {
  import delimited `dataset`
  append using `appendfile`
  save `appendfile`
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I get the following error because of the date format. I am trying to fix it ```variable date is str7 in master but float in using data
    You could specify append's force option to ignore this string/numeric mismatch.  The using variable would then be treated as if it contained "".
```

Comment: In some files your date is stored as text and some as Stata dates. When appending, the format has to be the same in variables with the same name. Which format do you prefer? Do not use force as it will drop data not on the same format

Comment: I'd like to have the dates in the .csv files to be in the date format. The dates I have the .csv files are of the form "Year - month number", e.g. 2011-01 for January of 2011, but the the dates in dataset1 are of the form "Year"+"m"+"month number", like "2011m1" for January 2011.  I tried to convert the dates of .csv files using the stata date function but I do not get the result wanted. My code is ```generate numdate = date(date, "YM")```.